# Xbox controller won't work with Dishonered PC game (played through steam and wine)

Tags: wine, steam, gamepad, xbox-360

I installed the windows version of Steam in my Ubuntu 13.04 OS because of older pc games I have. Everything works fine except when I play Dishonered, it won't detect my xbox controller. I have tried installing xpad/xboxdrv but it still won't work. I could technically use qjoypad, but qjoypad for me is buggy. Would rather prefer my controller communicate directly with the game rather than a third party software.

I know Ubuntu can detect my controller cause it lists it when I type in lsusb in the terminal. Any suggestions on what I could do to have my xbox controller running in the windows version of steam?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Wine doesn't have support for Xinput, which is the API used by most modern games for Xbox360 gamepad support. There is a workaround for it, the same you would use for Windows and an old non-Xbox360 gamepad, but it's a little complicated, see:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/xboxdrv/wgY0sp-drD8